# Get file from current directory and print in the same line there files with same extension

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line

The script should list the current directory files divided by suffix (and end the list  without suffixes).

example (also ".extension:")

```
.c: first.c main.c var.c
.h: const.h first.h
.odt: relazione.odt
makefile README COPYING
```

I'm trying with ls, sort, uniq but I can't.
Somebody can help me?

I wrote a solution in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

dictionary={}

for dirpath,_,files in os.walk("./"):
    for f in files:
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
        _ , ext = os.path.splitext(path)
        if ext not in dictionary:
            dictionary[ext] = []
        dictionary[ext].append(f)

for k in dictionary:
    if k != "":
        print(k, end=": ")
        for i in dictionary.get(k):
            print(i, end= " ")
        print("")

for i in dictionary.get(""):
    print(i, end= " ")
print("")
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I tried this for get the suffix ls | sort -t . | awk -F '.'  '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `find + awk` script:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
awk -v RS='\0' -F. '{$0 = substr($0, 3)} NF>1{ext[$NF] = ext[$NF] OFS $0; next}
{noext = noext $0 OFS} END{for (e in ext) print "." e ":" ext[e]; print noext}'
```

Comment: Can you explain what you do in this script? It only works with the first file it finds

Comment: I have tested it with a directory with hundreds of files and it works fine. It uses awk's associative array to create array with index as extension names of each file.

Comment: @anubhava Depends what awk it is, pretty sure some of the old ones can't have null chars as RS.

Comment: @123 You are right, I had "mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan" I now install "GNU Awk 4.1.1" and the (@)anubhava script works

Answer (score 3):

Could use Perl.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die "Too many args. Please supply one directory\n" if @ARGV > 1;
die "Too few args. Please supply one directory\n" if @ARGV < 1;

opendir (my $dir, "$ARGV[0]") || die "$ARGV[0]: $!\n" ;
my %extfiles;
my @Others;
while (my $file = readdir $dir){
        next if (-d "./$file");
        if($file =~ /^..*(\.[^\.]*)$/){
                $extfiles{$1}=$extfiles{$1}?"$extfiles{$1} $file":"$file"
        }
        else{
                push @Others,$file
        }
}
closedir $dir;

#print "Files with extensions\n\n";
for my $extension (keys %extfiles){
        print "$extension: $extfiles{$extension}\n";
}

#print "\nFiles without extensions\n\n";

print join (" ",@Others),"\n";
```

Save in a file e.g

```
ListExt.pl
```

Run as:

```
perl ListExt.pl $Dir
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
       fname = ARGV[i]
       n = split(fname,parts,/\./)
       ext = ( n>1 ? parts[n] : "none" )
       ext2files[ext] = ext2files[ext] OFS fname
    }
    for (ext in ext2files) {
        print ext ":" ext2files[ext]
    }
    exit
}' *
```

Comment: Wont this list directories as well?

Comment: The post was tagged *Bash Shell Awk Command line* In that context -- this is the *right answer*. I am a Perl fan btw.

Comment: @EdMorton:  Needs to be `split(fname,parts,/\./)` to split on a literal `.`

Comment: @dawg yup, you're right, fixed thanks. I did not expect that since the 3rd arg for split() is a field separator (like `FS`) and in a field separator any single character is treated literally BUT that functionality applies when that 3rd arg is a string (dynamic regexp), not a regexp literal as I had written. This is a case where using `"."` would produce different results to `/./`.

Comment: @123 yes it will list directories and it will not list files that start with `.`, I expect the OP will let us know if any of that's an issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ ls -lndp *
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:01 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:01 README
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  2 06:36 a.b.c
drwxr-xr-x  2 501  0  68 May  2 06:15 adir.dir/
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:00 const.h
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  2 08:00 file name with a space.doc
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:00 first.c
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:00 first.h
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:00 main.c
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:01 makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:01 relazione.odt
-rw-r--r--  1 501  0   0 May  1 15:00 var.c
```

Assuming you want to not include directories, you can filter out the directories and just feed file names to `awk`:

```
awk '{n=split($0, parts, /\./)
      ext = ( n>1 ? parts[n] : "none" )
      ext2files[ext] = ext2files[ext] OFS $0
      }
   END{
      for (ext in ext2files) 
         print ext ":" ext2files[ext]
      }' <(for fn in *; do  [ ! -d "$fn" ] && echo "$fn"; done)
h: const.h first.h
none: COPYING README makefile
odt: relazione.odt
doc: file name with a space.doc
c: a.b.c first.c main.c var.c
```

If you want the output sorted, and you have `gawk` you can write a comparison function:

```
gawk ' function cmp_idx(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
         if (i1=="" || i2=="")
            return (i1=="") ? 1 : -1 
         return (i1 < i2) ? -1 : (i1 != i2)
      }
      {
      n=split($0, parts, /\./)
      ext = ( n>1 ? parts[n] : "" )
      ext2files[ext] = (ext2files[ext] ? ext2files[ext] OFS $0 : $0)
      }
   END{
      PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "cmp_idx"
      for (ext in ext2files) 
         print (ext ? ext ": " ext2files[ext] : ext2files[ext])
      }' <(for fn in *; do  [ ! -d "$fn" ] && echo "$fn"; done)
c: a.b.c first.c main.c var.c
doc: file name with a space.doc
h: const.h first.h
odt: relazione.odt
COPYING README makefile
```

Comment: The "none files" must be placed at the bottom without prefix "none:"

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -d *.* 2>/dev/null | cut -d. -f2- | sort -u | while read i ; do
    echo -n ."$i":' '
    for j in *."$i" ; do
         echo -n "$j"' '
    done
    echo
done
ls | grep -v '\.' | tr '\n' ' '
```